# Prove that $||\nabla u||^2+||\nabla v||^2=\frac{0.5}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ if $x=2uv, y=u^2-v^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

> $x,y$ are functions of $u,v$ and $x=2uv, y=u^2-v^2$. There's an inverse map from such that $u,v$ are functions of $x,y$. Prove that $$||\nabla u||^2+||\nabla v||^2=\frac{0.5}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

This is an exercise for implicit differentiation. I thought of the following:
$$
u_u=v_x 2v+v_y 2v\\
v_v=v_x 2u-v_y 2v\\
u_u=u_x 2v+u_y 2u\\
u_v=u_x 2u-u_y 2v
$$
Even if this is correct I don't see how we can factor out the gradients from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiate $x=2uv$ and $y=u^2 - v^2$ each with respect to $x$ and with respect to $y$, to get four equations:

$$\begin{cases} u_x v + uv_x = 0.5 \ \\ uu_y - vv_y = 0.5  \\ u_yv + uv_y = 0 \\ uu_x - vv_x = 0 \end{cases}$$

Multiply the last equation by $v$ to get: $(vu_x)u = v^2 v_x$, and substitute $vu_x = 0.5 - uv_x$ to get:

$$v_x = \frac{u}{2(u^2 + v^2)}$$

which gives (using the last equation once more):

$$u_x = \frac{v}{2(u^2+v^2)}$$

Doing the same thing to the other equations we get:

$$v_y = -\frac{v}{2(u^2 + v^2)}$$

and:

$$u_y = \frac{u}{2(u^2+v^2)}$$

It's then clear that:

$$\|\nabla u\|^2 + \|\nabla v\|^2 = \frac{0.5}{(u^2 + v^2)}$$

notice that:

$$x^2 + y^2 = u^4 + v^4 + 2u^2v^2 = (u^2 + v^2)^2, \therefore \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = u^2 +v^2$$

so we get the desired equation.

Comment: I didn't understand how you got the initial system, also you have $v$ and $u$ not differentiated in the system?

Comment: @Yos e.g. $x = 2uv$, differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ to get $1 = 2(uv)_x$. Now $(uv)_x = u_x v + uv_x$ (product rule). This gives the first equation. And $x = 2uv$, differentiate both sides with respect to $y$ to get $0 = 2(uv)_y$ and use the product rule. This gives the third equation. Etc.

Comment: I've never seen anything like this in implicit differentiation category...

Comment: @Yos then I'm glad you learned something new!